# Custom UITableViewCell On Autorelease causes a crash in application

Tags: iphone, ios, uitableview, autorelease

I have a custom cell for my table view which I have designed using interface builder. In its .m file I have some code like this to fetch the xib from the bundle for the custom cell.

```
- (id)initWithStyle:(UITableViewCellStyle)style reuseIdentifier:(NSString *)reuseIdentifier
{
    self = [super initWithStyle:style reuseIdentifier:reuseIdentifier];
    if (self) {
        NSArray *nibArray = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SubItemsCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];
        self = [nibArray objectAtIndex:0];    }
    return self;
}
```

Then when I use this cell in my cellForRowAtIndexPath method and pass it an autorelease message

```
if (!cellForSubItems) {
    cellForSubItems = [[[SubItemsCustomCell alloc] initWithStyle:UITableViewCellStyleDefault reuseIdentifier:@"SubItemCell"] autorelease];
}
```

it crashes when i scroll the tableView giving a message,

```
-[SubItemsCustomCell release]: message sent to deallocated instance 0xed198b0
```

It never crashed when I made a custom cell using code, but it does here, why is it so??
Also when I dont autorelease it, it runs absolutely fine, but obviously it will have memory leaks.
Kindly Help me out with this one. Thanks In Advance.

EDIT: I am not using ARC.

Comment: ok just see my another way to use customcell in cellForRawAtIndexPath: Method..]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

try my bellow code for add cell in `UITableView`

```
- (UITableViewCell *)tableView:(UITableView *)tableView cellForRowAtIndexPath:(NSIndexPath *)indexPath
    {
        SubItemsCustomCell *cell = (SubItemsCustomCell *) [tableView      dequeueReusableCellWithIdentifier:nil];

        if (cell == nil) 
        {

            NSArray *topLevelObjects = [[NSBundle mainBundle] loadNibNamed:@"SubItemsCustomCell" owner:self options:nil];

            for (id currentObject in topLevelObjects){
                if ([currentObject isKindOfClass:[UITableViewCell class]]){
                    cell =  (SubItemsCustomCell *) currentObject;
                    break;
                }
            }
             ///do something here
        }

        return cell;
    }
```

i hope this help you...

:)

Comment: Ok Let me try it. This also tells me that I should comment my code used to fetch the xib file in my .m file of the custom cell.

Comment: ok mate,i also use custom cell with NIB its work fine ... try it :)

Comment: Ya that worked fine... Thanks for the answer.. I see that here since we only use a reference ton the array with nib, we need not release its memory since we never allocated one to it.. thanks again for lighting my bulb. i had seen such code quite back, but I failed to use it when needed.

Answer (score 2):

Your init method looks very wrong.

At the time it is called, an object has already been allocated. Then, you replace that object with something you load from a nib. Here you already leak the old instance, which you should release first. The new object from the nib is autoreleased (see naming conventions), so you should retain it here.

I strongly suggest removing that bogus code altogether. You don't want to manually call alloc/init, just to replace it with something from a nib there. Load from the nib directly.

So yes, your code may leak, but probably not the way you thought of.

Comment: Thanks for the explanation, your answer explains a whole lot. Now I know exactly where and how I was wrong. And you are right we dont need to alloc and init if its being fetched from the nib file directly.